# Entity Frameworkcore - Custom Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My table was created in the database. But the primary key I want should be 10 characters long. The primary key must be randomly generated. So it should be a 10-digit random number, not auto-incrementing. How can I do that?

1- The primary key must be 10 characters long. For example: 1674058910
2- The primary key must be randomly generated. It should not be in ascending order.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove any config for `Auto increment` like `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute.

2 - Create `BaseEntity.cs` class :

```
public class BaseEntity
{
   public BaseEntity()
   {
      Id = new Random().Next(1000000000,Int32.MaxValue);
   }

   public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

3 - inherit this class in all of you entity like this:

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

4 - ***Important***: you may have a conflict in your id, check the id before insert in the `database`.